# How do I split string of values in XSLT1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string of single values and ranges, and I want to split them and put them in order of single values together (comma separated) and ranges together (comma separated), using XSLT1.0.  I don't want the result in form of XML nodes, I do want the result on the same line.  I have found that existing solutions here on Stack Exchange works, but it puts them on different lines as XML nodes.

The string is:

Input: `<mark>9, 11, 345-900, 100-200, 1023, 200-400, 99</mark>`
Desired Output: `9, 11, 1023, 99, 345-900, 100-200, 200-400`

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="mark">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeStringWithoutHyphen">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeStringWithHyphen">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--############################################################-->
    <!--## Template to tokenize strings                           ##-->
    <!--############################################################-->
    <xsl:template name="separatestrings">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenizeStringWithHyphen">
        <!--passed template parameter -->
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:variable name="stringContainsHyphen" select="contains(substring-before($list,$delimiter),'-')"/>
                <!--<test><xsl:value-of select="$stringContainsHyphen"/></test>-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$stringContainsHyphen = true()">

                            <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($list,$delimiter))"/>

                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeStringWithHyphen">
                    <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$list = ''">
                        <xsl:text/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>

                            <xsl:value-of select="$list"/>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenizeStringWithoutHyphen">
        <!--passed template parameter -->
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:variable name="stringContainsHyphen" select="contains(substring-before($list,$delimiter),'-')"/>
                <!--<test><xsl:value-of select="$stringContainsHyphen"/></test>-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$stringContainsHyphen = false()">
                        <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($list,$delimiter))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeStringWithoutHyphen">
                    <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your input and expected output **as code**.

Comment: And you would also like the tokens in output to be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: I will have numbers as input, so I don't need them sorted alphabetically.  But, I do want all the numbers together and all the ranges together.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the result in form of XML nodes, I do want the result on
>   the same line.

If you want to sort the values, you must tokenize them into nodes first. Then sort the nodes and output them back as text values in a single line:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="mark">
    <xsl:variable name="tokens">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tokens)/token">
        <xsl:sort select="number(contains(., '-'))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="', '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </token>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </token>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael.  Just curious, what if I can't use xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"

Comment: Then it gets much more complicated. All major XSLT 1.0 processors support the exsl:node-set() extension function, and for a good reason.

Comment: This is first time I am using Stack exchange, how do I accept and close ?  Thanks for your help.